# Solve $x^2y' + xy + 1 = 0$ first order differential equation. Where is my mistake?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Solve $x^2y' + xy + 1 = 0$ first order differential equation. The answer from the textbook is $xy = C - \ln |x|$. Here is my long (but wrong) solution and I can't see the mistake.

First I rewrite it as $y' + \dfrac{y}{x} = -\dfrac{1}{x^2}$, this is a first order linear differential equation. Let's consider $y' = -\dfrac{y}{x}$. From here $\dfrac{dy}{y} = -\dfrac{dx}{x}$ and $\ln y = - \ln x + C$ and $y = Ce^{\frac{1}{x}}$.

Now for the general solution assume $y = C(x)e^{\frac{1}{x}}$. Then $C'(x)e^{\frac{1}{x}} - \dfrac{C(x)e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x^2} + \dfrac{C(x)e{\frac{1}{x}}}{x} = -\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ and $C'(x) - \dfrac{C(x)}{x^2} + \dfrac{C(x)}{x} = -\dfrac{1}{x^2e^{\frac{1}{x}}}$. Let $u \equiv C(x)$. We have $u' - u(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x^2}) = -\dfrac{1}{x^2e^{\frac{1}{x}}}$ This is another linear differential equation. Let's consider $\dfrac{du}{u} = dx(\dfrac{1}{x} - \dfrac{1}{x^2})$. Integrating we have $\ln u = \ln x + \dfrac{1}{x} + C_1$ and $u = C_1xe^{\frac{1}{x}}$. Now suppose $u = C_1(x)xe^{\frac{1}{x}}$. Then $C_1'(x)xe^{\frac{1}{x}} + C_1(x)e^{\frac{1}{x}} - \dfrac{C_1(x)e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x} - C_1(x)e^{\frac{1}{x}}(1 - \dfrac{1}{x}) = -\dfrac{1}{x^2e^{\frac{1}{x}}}$ and $C_1'(x)x + C_1(x) - \dfrac{C_1(x)}{x} - C_1(x)(1 - \dfrac{1}{x}) = -\dfrac{1}{x^2e^{\frac{2}{x}}}$ and finally $C_1'(x) = -\dfrac{1}{x^2e^{\frac{2}{x}}}$. Also before passing to integration suppose $x = \dfrac{1}{\ln z}$. Then $dx = \dfrac{dz}{z \ln^2 z}$. So $$C_1(x) = - \int {\dfrac{dx}{x^2e^{\frac{2}{x}}}} = - \int{zdz} = -z^2/2 + C = -e^{\frac{2}{x}} + C$$ Then finally $y = C(x)e^{\frac{1}{x}} \equiv ue^{\frac{1}{x}} = C_1(x)xe^{\frac{2}{x}} =-e^{\frac{4}{x}}x + Cxe^{\frac{2}{x}}$.

Comment: $$e^{-\log x}=x^{-1}=\frac1x,$$ not $e^{1/x}.$

Comment: How $\ln{y}=-\ln{x}$ then $y=e^{1/x}$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews What a huge facepalm. So I've basically solved a completely different problem? lol

Comment: Also, $C$ is not a function of $x.$

Comment: This is much easier to solve with a little cleverness: $$xy'+y=(xy)'.$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That's a technique from my book. First solve the corresponding homogenous equation, then consider a solution of the same form, but instead of the constant $C$ consider a function $C(x)$. Plug into the equation, solve and find $C(x)$.

Comment: Ah, better to start a new paragraph, and preface with "Now, for the general equation, assume ..."

Comment: Thanks, I edited as you suggested

Comment: $\ln y = - \ln x + C \Rightarrow \ln y + \ln x = C \Rightarrow \ln (y x) = C \Rightarrow y x = e^c$

Comment: Your solution is a solution for $\